# Angular FormGroup Validation on an addControl

Tags: angular

I Am using Angular 9.

I would like to validate the form.

I have the following:

**ts**

```
  public fg: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});

            ...

            const person: Person = {x: i, y: j, personId: personId, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email, companyName: this.approvalEdit.companyName, staffCode: staffCode};
            this.fg.addControl('userName['+i+']['+j+']', new FormControl(person));
```

Do you know where I need to add `Validators.required`?

I have tried `new FormControl(person, [Validators.required])`, but I think my problem might be that `person` is an object, and it is always present. I need to check that `person.personId` is persent.

**html**

```
<input formControlName="userName[{{i}}][{{j}}]" matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': fg.get('userName['+i+']['+j+']').touched && fg.get('userName['+i+']['+j+']').invalid}">
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#validating-input-in-reactive-forms; https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl

Comment: `new FormControl(person, Validators.required)`

Comment: I have tried that, but it doesn't validate (no errors, but no validation). Perhaps my error is elsewhere.  I have also tried:  `new FormControl(person, [Validators.required])`.

Comment: I think my problem might be that `person` is an object, and it is always present. I need to check that `person.personId` is persent.

Comment: You could maybe use custom validator: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators. Also in general https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms. Your code is VERY weird, which makes it hard to give a good suggestion. And why is person always present? Can't it be null if not chosen? Why do you use `userName[{{i}}][{{j}}]` instead of a `FormArray` ?